# Website doesn't appear unless www. is used?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

There is some sort of DNS error on my clients website that is hosted by HeartInternet. For some reason the site does not appear unless `www.` is specified explicitly.

Works: http://www.elmhaven-marina.co.uk

Doesn't Work: http://elmhaven-marina.co.uk

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "@" A record pointing to elmhaven-marina.co.uk in your DNS

Comment: I have added an A record with name "@" and IP address "79.170.44.85" and it appears to be working fine now. I do not understand why this is automagically working now. How does it know that I meant www. and what does "@" mean? cheers

Comment: The "@" symbol is used when there is not a prefix for the domain name. It represents the 'naked domain'. eg. example.com

Comment: Cheers, so presumably the hosting company has already mapped the 'naked domain' to the web hosting package

Answer (score 1):

The DNS record simply doesn't have an entry for "www." then. It needs a CNAME pointing "www." to "@", meaning, an alias for the raw domain.

Comment: I prefer redirecting the user to the canonical domain instead of having an alias like that.